# Extracting values from HTML file into the QGIS Graphic Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, html, qgis-grass-plugin

I've built a little model which does a simple linear regression between values of a point layer and a raster. The model works fine, but I cannot find a way to extract the regression coefficients (a and b) from the output HTML of the 'r.regression.line' algorithm for further use within the model.

So far I've tried eval in the expression calculator but couldn't really figure out how to use it. Also, I found some Python code (beautifulsoup) which seems to fit the problem; the issue here is my lack of mental capacity.

Below you will find the output HTML from the regression algorithm and a picture of the model.

```html
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head><body><p>y = a + b*x
</br>   a (Offset): 11.935652
</br>   b (Gain): -9.351144
</br>   R (sumXY - sumX*sumY/N): -0.469817
</br>   N (Number of elements): 399
</br>   F (F-test significance): 112.449603
</br>   meanX (Mean of map1): 0.566675
</br>   sdX (Standard deviation of map1): 0.069080
</br>   meanY (Mean of map2): 6.636591
</br>   sdY (Standard deviation of map2): 1.374951
</br></p></body></html>
```

[image: model]

[image: output html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script you can add to a model that extracts the slope and intercept from the GRASS HTML output you provided.

This script uses the [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) included in the standard library

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from qgis.processing import alg


class GRASSHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.coeffs = {}

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if ": " in data:
            data = data.strip().split(": ")
            self.coeffs[data[0]] = float(data[1])


@alg(name="getcoeffs", label=alg.tr("Get Coeffs"), group='grassscripts', group_label='Grass Scripts')
@alg.input(type=alg.FILE, name="INPUT_HTML", label="Input HTML")
@alg.output(type=alg.NUMBER, name="SLOPE", label="Output slope")
@alg.output(type=alg.NUMBER, name="INTERCEPT", label="Output intercept")

def getcoeffs(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """Get coeffs from grass html"""

    html_file = instance.parameterAsString(parameters, "INPUT_HTML", context)

    with open(html_file) as fp:
        parser = GRASSHTMLParser()
        parser.feed(fp.read())

    intercept = parser.coeffs["a (Offset)"]
    slope = parser.coeffs["b (Gain)"]

    return {'SLOPE': slope, 'INTERCEPT': intercept}
```

Alternatively, this version uses the [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) package which isn't installed by default. On Linux `pip install beautifulsoup4` will work. Other OS's may need a different installation method.

```py
from qgis.processing import alg
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


@alg(name="getcoeffs", label=alg.tr("Get Coeffs"), group='grassscripts', group_label='Grass Scripts')
@alg.input(type=alg.FILE, name="INPUT_HTML", label="Input HTML")
@alg.output(type=alg.NUMBER, name="SLOPE", label="Output slope")
@alg.output(type=alg.NUMBER, name="INTERCEPT", label="Output intercept")

def getcoeffs(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """Get coeffs from GRASS HTML"""

    html_file = instance.parameterAsString(parameters, "INPUT_HTML", context)

    with open(html_file) as fp:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')

    lines = [l.strip().split(": ") for l in soup.p.text.split("\n") if ": " in l]
    coeffs = {k: float(v) for k, v in lines}
    
    intercept = coeffs["a (Offset)"]
    slope = coeffs["b (Gain)"]


    return {'SLOPE': slope, 'INTERCEPT': intercept}
```

You can then add it as a script tool to QGIS and use it in models:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. Worked right away. Admire the work you do here.